# Running a function when click a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, I'm trying to add them the option each time I click the divs an alert appears. This is the javascript code I'm using.

```
$('.pre').click(function() {
    alert("Pre");
});

$('.back').click(function() {
    alert("back");
});
```

This is the HTML I'm using

```
<div class="lb_controls">
  <div id="pre"><span class="lb_previous">&lt;</span></div>
       <span class="lb_title">Ornamental Lights</span>
  <div id="back"><span class="lb_next">&gt;</span></div>   
</div>
```

Currently I have a demo for this. It's [here](http://jsbin.com/vuyas/2)

'm wondering if this is the best way, instead of having the two divs it should better to use to images? What do you think?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would it be better with images? Either you want images or you want elements, but one isn't better than the other, it depends on what you want/need, and it's a bit like asking if the yellow car is better than the red car?

Comment: @adeneo He was asking in terms of Javascript, which way would cause the function to run if one of those didn't work... or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, What I'm trying to do is with javascript, but if it doesn't work, would images work?

Comment: BTW why is the id given in html and class called in jquery ?

Comment: Nope, if it doesn't work, images wouldn't work either. Wrong selectors are wrong selectors regardless of what elements you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using class like this..

**Markup:**

```
<div id="pre" class="pre"><span class="lb_previous">&lt;</span></div>
<div id="back"  class="back"><span class="lb_next">&gt;</span></div>
```

**Javascript:**

**Using Class:**

```
$('.pre').click(function() {
    alert("Pre");
});
$('.back').click(function() {
    alert("back");
});
```

**Using ID:**

```
$('#pre').click(function() {
        alert("Pre");
    });
    $('#back').click(function() {
        alert("back");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using **IDs** but pointing to **Classes** in the JS

JS:

```
$('#pre').click(function() {
    alert("Pre");
});

$('#back').click(function() {
    alert("back");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using class selectors . But "pre" and "back" are id

```
   $('#pre').click(function() {
        alert("Pre");
    });

    $('#back').click(function() {
        alert("back");
    });
```

Comment: I think it is typo error.

Comment: @adamj: I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @BoltClock Dammit! My English fails me! What word was I looking for I have no clue haha